# Custom JavaScript without RequireJS

Tags: magento2, requirejs

> Is it possible to add **custom JS to Magento 2,** **without RequireJS** while avoiding render-blocking problems?
>
> **This error keeps coming: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch**

That error creates render-blocking which means that 50% of page loads are missing the navigation menu and cart

Comment: Isn't possible.

Comment: I found my problem, I linked to a third party script which included an anonymous define() call